# Xcode 5 ScrollView scroll too far

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode5

After I updated my project to Xcode5 my ScrollView scrolls too far. Before Xcode5 I never had any problems with my ScrollViews.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little, add some code, screenshots (and compare with Safari when running on iOS7).

Comment: It's always a good idea to make your question explicit, like: *Did something change in Xcode5 or iOS7 to make scroll views behave differently?*

Comment: Not sure you can give any answer to this as it lacks everything that makes a question an actual question such as a question `?` voted to close. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was able to resolve the error, it was the autolayout.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self respondsToSelector: @selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

When the UIScrollView is not a root view in the Controller, you also needs to add Constraints (left, right, top, bottom) between your scroll view and the root view.